# textbf and textit text dont show up on phone

Tags: pdftex, templates, overleaf, resume

I'm using textit and textbf on my resume, but upon checking how my resume looks on my phone, it seems that a) nothing is bolded or italicized, and b) the things that are supposed to be bolded are kind of overlapping the other words?

Here's a snippet of what I'm doing

```
\item Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet I dont know the rest of the \textbf{Lorem Ipsum.}
```

on my phone this shows up with no bold and in some places it will overlap other text. Is there a way around this/a fix?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you compile the cv. And please tell us what's entailed by "checking how the resume looks on [the] phone". Are you looking at a pdf file?

Comment: I compile it on overleaf with the compiler pdflatex. Looking at it on my phone just means like when I download it from overleaf as a pdf.

Comment: unlike html pdf is already typeset so the fonts really don't change when you view on different devices, (it is possible to make pdf without the fonts embedded but that is not the default)

Comment: what font are you using, does it have a matching bold font?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using a pdf template which says 
```\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} ``` at the start which I guess means that I'm using sans 11pt. Possibly the problem is with me using ```moderncv```

Comment: Here are the imports that I have:
```\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{pdfpages}%

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[scale=0.8,top=0.5cm, bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{moderncvheadiii}
\usepackage{moderncvbodyiii}
\xpatchcmd\cventry{,}{}{}{}```
also oddly enough the symbols that I have (linkedin symbol, github symbol, email symbol) dont show up on mobile either